# Canvas shining star background performance issue

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, drawimage

I've got an issue with an experiment I'm working on.

My plan is to have a beautiful and shining stars Background on a whole page.
Using that wondeful tutorial (http://timothypoon.com/blog/2011/01/19/html5-canvas-particle-animation/) I managed to get the perfect background.
I use a static canvas to display static stars and an animated canvas for the shining ones.

The fact is it's very memory hungry! On chrome and opera it runs quite smoothly, but on firefox IE or tablet, it was a total mess 1s to render each frame etc... It is worse on pages where HEIGHT is huge.

So i went into some optimisations:

-Using a buffer canvas, the problem was createRadialGradient which was called 1500 times each frame

-Using a big buffer canvas, and 1 canvas for each stars with an only call to createRadialGradient at init.

-Remove that buffer canvas and drawing every stars canvas to the main one

That last optimisation was the best i could achieve so i wrote a fiddle displaying how is the code right now.

```
   //Buffering the star image
    this.scanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.scanvas.width=2*this.r;
    this.scanvas.height=2*this.r;
    this.scon=this.scanvas.getContext('2d');
    g = this.scon.createRadialGradient(this.r,this.r,0,this.r,this.r,this.r);
    g.addColorStop(0.0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)');
    g.addColorStop(this.stop, 'rgba('+this.color.r+','+this.color.g+','+this.color.b+','+this.stop+')');
    g.addColorStop(1.0, 'rgba('+this.color.r+','+this.color.g+','+this.color.b+',0)');
    this.scon.fillStyle = g;
    this.scon.fillRect(0,0,2*this.r,2*this.r);
```

That's the point where I need you:

-A way to adjust the number of shining stars according to the user perfomance

-Optimisation tips

Thanks in advance to everyone minding to help me and I apologize if I made grammar mistakes, my english isn't perfect.

**EDIT**
Thanks for your feedbacks,
Let me explains the whole process,
Every stars has it's own different gradient and size, that's why I stored it into a personal canvas, the shining effect is only done by scaling that canvas on the main one with drawImage.

I think the best would be to prerender 50 or 100 different stars in a buffer canvas then picking and drawing a random one, don't you think?

**EDIT2**

Updated fiddle according to Warlock great advises, one prerendered star, scaled to match the current size. The stars are less pretty, but the whole thing runs a lot smoother.

**EDIT3**

Updated fiddle to use a sprite sheet. Gorgeous!!!!

```
 //generate the star strip
    var len=(ttlm/rint)|0;
    scanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    scanvas.width=len*2*r;
    scanvas.height=2*r;
    scon=scanvas.getContext('2d');
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var newo = (i/len);
        var cr = r*newo;
        g = scon.createRadialGradient(2*r*i+r,r,0,2*r*i+r,r,(cr <= 2 ? 2 : cr));
        g.addColorStop(0.0, 'rgba(200,220,255,'+newo+')');
        g.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(200,220,255,'+(newo*.7)+')');
        g.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(150,170,205,'+(newo*.2)+')');
        g.addColorStop(0.7, 'rgba(150,170,205,0)');
        scon.fillStyle = g;
        scon.fillRect(2*r*i,0,2*r,2*r);         
    }
```

**EDIT 4(Final)**

**Dynamic stars creations**

```
function draw() {
    frameTime.push(Date.now());    
    con.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    for(var i = 0, len = pxs.length; i < len; i++) {
        pxs[i].fade();
        pxs[i].draw();
    }   
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    if(allowMore === true && frameTime.length == monitoredFrame)
    {
        if(getAvgTime()<threshold && pxs.length<totalStars ) 
        {
            addStars();         
        }
        else
        {
            allowMore=false;
            static=true;
            fillpxs(totalStars-pxs.length,pxss);
            drawstatic();
            static=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the updated and final fiddle, with spritesheet, dynamic stars creation and several optimisations. If you see anything else i should update don't hesitate.

**POST EDIT** Reenabled shooting stars/Prototyped object/got rid of Jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/macintox/K8YTu/32/

Thanks everyone who helped me, that was really kind and instructive, and I hope it will help somebody sometimes.

Aesdotjs.
PS: I'm so happy. After testing, that script run smoothly on every browser even IE9. Yatta!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Adopting to browser performance

To measure capability of the user's setup you can implement a dynamic star creator which stops at a certain threshold.

For example, in your code you define a minimum number of stars to draw. Then in your main loop you measure the time and if the time spent drawing the stars are less than your max threshold you add 10 more stars (I'm just throwing out a number here).

Not many are aware of that [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) gives an argument ([DOMHighResTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp)) to the function it calls with time in milliseconds spent since last request. This will help you keep track of load and as we know that 60 fps is about 16.7 ms per frame we can set a threshold a little under this to be optimal and still allow some overhead for other browser stuff.

A code could look like this:

```
var minCount = 100,   /// minimum number of stars
    batchCount = 10,  /// stars to add each frame
    threshold= 14,    /// milliseconds for each frame used
    allowMore = true; /// keep adding

/// generate initial stars
generateStarts(minCount);

/// timeUsed contains the time in ms since last requestAnimationFrame was called
function loop(timeUsed) {

    if (allowMore === true && timeUsed < threshold) {
        addMoreStars(batchNumber);
    } else {
        allowMore = false;
    }

    /// render stars

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

Just note that this is a bit simplified. You will need to run a few rounds first and measure the average to have this work better as you can and will get peak when you add stars (and due to other browser operations).

So add stars, measure a few rounds, if average is below threshold add stars and repeat.

## Optimizations

### Sprite-sheets

As to optimizations sprite-sheets are the way to go. And they don't have to just be the stars (I'll try to explain below).

The gradient and arc is the costly part of this applications. Even when pre-rendering a single star there is cost in resizing so many stars due to interpolation etc.

When there becomes a lot of costly operations it is better to do a compromise with memory usage and pre-render everything you can.

For example: render the various sizes by first rendering a big star using gradient and arc.
Use that star to draw the other sizes as a strip of stars with the same cell size.

Now, draw only *half* of the number of stars using the sprite-sheet and draw *clipped* parts of the sprite-sheet (and not re-sized). Then rotate the canvas 90 degrees and draw the canvas *itself* on top of itself in a different position (the canvas becoming a big "sprite-sheet" in itself).

Rotating 90 degrees is not so performance hungry as other degrees (0, 90, 180, 270 are optimized). This will give you the illusion of having the actual amount of stars and since it's rotated we are not able to detect a repetitive pattern that easy.

A single `drawImage` operation of canvas is faster than many small draw operations of all the stars.

(and of course, you can do this many times instead of just once up to a point right before where you start see patterns - there is no key answer to how many, what size etc. so to find the right balance is always an experiment).

### Integer numbers

Other optimizations can be using only integer positions and sizes. When you use float numbers sub-pixeling is activated which is costly as the browser need to calculate anti-alias for the offset pixels.

Using integer values can help as sub-pixeling isn't needed (but this doesn't mean the image won't be interpolated if not 1:1 dimension).

### Memory bounds

You can also help the underlying low-lowel bitmap handling a tiny bit by using sizes and positions dividable on 4. This has to do with memory copy and low-level clipping. You can always make several sprite-sheet to variate positions within a cell that is dividable on 4.

This trick is more valuable on slower computers (ie. typical consumer spec'ed computers).

### Turn off anti-aliasing

Turn off anti-aliasing for images. This will help performance but will give a little more rough result of the stars. To turn off image anti-aliasing do this:

```
ctx.webkitEnableImageSmoothing = false;
ctx.mozEnableImageSmoothing = false;
ctx.enableImageSmoothing = false;
```

You will by doing this see a noticeable improvement in performance as long as you use `drawImage` to render the stars.

### Cache everything

Cache everything you can cache, being the star image as well as variables.

When you do this `stars.length` the browser's parser need to first find `stars` and then traverse that tree to find `length` - for each round (this may be optimized in some browsers).

If you first cache this to a variable `var len = stars.length` the browser only need to traverse the tree and branch once and in the loop it will only need to look up the local scope to find variable `len` which is faster.

### Resolution reduction

You can also reduce resolution in half, ie. do everything at half the target size. In the final step draw your render enlarged to full size. This will save you initially 75% render area but give you a bit low-res look as a result.

From the professional video world we often use low-resolution when things are animated (primarily moving) as the eye/brain patch up (or can't detect) so much details when objects are moving and therefor isn't so noticeable. If this can help here must be tested - perhaps not since the stars aren't actually moving, but worth a try for the second benefit: increased performance.

Comment: Wow, What can I say... thanks, a lot!
I will check all those clues out, really great explanation!
I'll post updated fiddle.

Comment: @user2755104 no problem. Don't forget to up-vote if answer was useful :-) PS. I fixed a "typo"/bug in the declarations (`timeUsed` should be `threshold`).

Comment: "Not many are aware of that requestAnimationFrame gives an argument to the function it calls with time in milliseconds spent since last request."
That argument isn't always the same depending on the browser.

Comment: @Aesdotjs it should be the same for all browsers. The only thing that may vary is its accuracy as it depends on the underlying API. The argument is always a [DOMHighResTimeStam](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp). Time itself may not be same as this depends on the browser implementation and how efficient it is (slower implementations spend more time etc.).

Comment: on firefox safari or ie , it returned undefined maybe the cause is the polyfill

Comment: @Aesdotjs it's because some of the browsers hasn't fully implemented the standard yet. The original WebKit doesn't implement rAF correctly (Safari, new Opera, the latter is suppose to implement Blink but it seem to be a mix..). IE is.. IE. In FF beta and Aurora it works fine (new version of FF will come with non-prefixed rAF). Chrome/Canary is fine. ([I made a small test here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/LjTJa/)). We can only sit and wait unfortunately... (and they say we need to wait until 2022 before things are fully implemented... no joke :-) )

Comment: http://www.webmonkey.com/2008/09/html_5_won_t_be_ready_until_2022dot_yes__2022dot/

Answer (score 2):

How about just creating a spritesheet of a star in its various stages of radial glow.

You could even use canvas to initially create the spritesheet.

Then use context.drawImage(spritesheet,spriteX,spriteY,starWidth,starHeight) to display the star.

Spritesheet images can be drawn to the screen very quickly with very little overhead.

You might further optimize by breaking the spritesheet into individual star images.

Good luck on your project :)

Comment: the thing is I updated the original code, so that it doesn't recalculate the glow but instead save the star in a canvas at init then scaling it down or up each frame

Comment: If you make a spritesheet (or individual sprite images), you won't have to do any scaling.  If you need different radius, color, etc, you would just make sprites for the variations.  Images render faster than canvas transforms.

Comment: scaling with drawimage is the clot ruinning the flow?

Answer (score 1):

**1. Minimize operations, related to the DOM;**

In the LINE 93 you are creating canvas:

```
this.scanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
```

You need only one canvas instead of this. Move canvas creation to the initialization step.

**2. Use integer coordinates for canvas;**

**3. Use Object Pool design pattern to improve performance.**

**4. In for loops cache the length variable:**

```
for(var i = 0; i < pxs.length; i++) {...
}
```

Better:

```
for(var i = 0, len = pxs.length; i < len; i++) {
...
}
```

Note: don't mix jquery with native js.

Comment: 1. I used a different canvas because each stars has it's own attributes, radius, fading, color

2. you mean for drawImage and fillRect?

3. go search that out

4. thanks for the tips